# server socket to accept connection from particular ip java

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I have a serversocket running on a port say 7761 in my server with ip say 10.2.110.43
now there are many client that run on different servers waiting for connection on port 7761, and write data in ascii format to that port.

I want the serversocket to verify the client-ipadress and then accept connection from client.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What is stopping you to verify the client IP in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind running under a `SecurityManager` and the list of IP addresses is static, you can accomplish this via the `security.policy` file. Just grant SocketPermission`"accept"` to only those IP addresses you want to accept connections from. However doing it in code or the firewall as suggested in another answers is probably preferable.

Comment: I too have been doing this in code but think this way you are suggesting is actually much cleaner. You can also configure ranges more easily since the list is in the file (although doing similar from code will also be quite easy).

Answer (score 5):

We see in the following code, we can't check address of counterparts *before* `accept()` but *after*:

```
Socket client = serverSocket.accept()
if( acceptedClients.contains( client.getInetAddress()) {
   ...
}
else {
   client.close();
}
```

With `acceptedClients` a collection of well known InetAddress.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the connection to reach your Java `ServerSocket#accept()` unless it comes from a specific IP, you will have to configure your firewall to do this.

You can always validate the IP address after the connection is established and immediately close it if it's not from the right IP.